# What is the difference between this "book" and a research paper?

Tags: publications, journals, books, terminology

I don't know a lot about the scientific research and its concepts. What is the difference between this [book](https://link.springer.com/referencework/10.1007/978-3-540-92910-9#toc) and any research paper?

From my understanding of the research world, I know that [link.springer](https://link.springer.com/) is a journal and journals publish research papers after reviewing. If that is the case, then what is that book doing in link.springer? Is it really just a book? or Do people call it "published book"?

Comment: It's a book, more specifically a collection. Springer is a publisher.

Comment: Springer publishes books as well as journals.  This particular item is a reference book published by Springer.  You can certainly cite chapters of a book like this.

Comment: @Brian Borchers: Make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Springer publishes books as well as journals. This particular item is a reference book published by Springer. You can certainly cite chapters of a book like this.